# header and footer merge for all other pages of html

Tags: html, css

I am making a website. I made separate Header and Footer files with separate css part..
I know only html and css. Plz tell me how to merge the header and footer for all the other pages. I am sending my code link from GitHub: https://github.com/AJITESH3210/WhatNext10-2
plz help me
I am student of class 9 only.

I have sent the source code. I tried a lot but I was not able to do

Comment: please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take some time to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You should first research for your own, tell what you've tried to achieve the goal and add a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your question if possible.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Include another HTML file in a HTML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988855/include-another-html-file-in-a-html-file)

Comment: do you want to merge your header and footer css code in everywhere?

Answer (score 0):

You can't import other files with **html only**. So, you have 3 methods to do this :

### Server-side include (recommended) :

Use a server side language (like php) to import files.

```php
<?php include 'header.php'; ?>
```

see [PHP include function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)

Files need to be php files, but you can write it like html files.
It's better because page is rendered on server and the client receive the page with header and footer merged.

### Client-side import :

Another method is to load differents parts with JS. Some frameworks (like Vuejs) comes with a components system. But, if you want to use vanilla js, you can use the fetch API

```js
fetch('linkto/header.html')
    .then(x => x.text())
    .then(html => {
        document.getElementById('your-container-id').innerHTML = html
    })
```

see [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

### Pre render pages :

If you use an assets compiler (webpack, parcel, rollup ...), you can import html files, and the compiler will generate a new html file, in a `/dist` directory for exemple, with parts imported, and other options like minify.

I never used this technique but here is a link for a [parcel plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/parcel-plugin-html-partials).